# Transform DOM Document to fragment with XSL in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

In Firefox and Chrome, I'm using something like this to convert XML documents to DOM fragments using XSL:

```
var xsl = document.implementation.createDocument(); // i.e. a DOM document
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(xsl);

var xml = document.implementation.createDocument(); // i.e. a DOM document
var fragment = processor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
```

In the actual code, `xsl` and `xml` are loaded from remote files using jQuery with `dataType: "xml"`, so are both XML documents.

What is the equivalent in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Achieved this in IE9 by converting the XML documents to strings and back: http://jsfiddle.net/hubfiddle/k5z6q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
 {
 ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=ex;
 }
 // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
 else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
   xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
   resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(resultDocument);
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't expect `xml.transformNode(xsl);` to just work, but apparently it does!